# Add HTTPS instead of HTTP for URLs for chatrooms on home page

Tags: support, feature-request

Since SE has implemented HTTPS weeks ago, the URLs for chat rooms still have HTTP.

For eg., [The Screening Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888)

Clicking on these URLs take to the related chatroom, but it takes forever to load which is possibly due to HTTP.

Can HTTPS be added in the URLs for chatrooms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to the [Meta.SE Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/250962) as of 16/06/2017

> 11. (Planning required) `chat.stackoverflow.com`, `chat.stackexchange.com`, and `chat.meta.stackexchange.com`

looking at the rest of the list it looks as if HTTPS still isn't fully done across the entire network but chatrooms are a part of the plan as

> Next up is chat and then https-only cookies.